# I am looking to fetch a table from a website in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importxml, xpath

I want the first table on this URL https://www.cashbackmonitor.com/cashback-store/amazon/ in my google sheet.

When I put this function (below), I can retrieve the first column of the first table e.g. Shop at Home, Top Cashback, etc. However, I am not able to get the Rate column of the table. Can someone please help.

```
=importxml("https://www.cashbackmonitor.com/cashback-store/booking.com/", "//td[@class='l lo']/a")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that won't be possible the way you trying because the fields you attempt to scrape are controlled by JavaScript and Google Sheets can't understand/import JS. You can test this simply by disabling JS for a given link and you will see what exactly can be imported into Google Sheets:

[image: 0]